How do Spanish politicians reconcile pro-Palestinian stance with opposition to Catalan and Basque statehood?
How do Spanish politicians reconcile pro-Palestinian stance with opposition to Catalan and Basque statehood?
Al-Jazeera suggests that the Spanish government strong pro-Palestinian stance is dictated by domestic considerations - showing sympathy to Catalan and Basque independantists:

Cristina Lopez, a public relations executive from Valencia, believes geopolitics have become subsumed into domestic issues in Spain.
“Like most, if not all, aspects of life in Spain, there is a domestic political subtext behind it and the conflict in Israel and Palestine is no different,” she said.
“Sanchez’s latest words are sending a message to his coalition partners, Basque and Catalan nationalists, whose support he relies on to govern.”
Spain’s inconclusive July elections meant Sanchez was forced to enlist the support of pro-independence parties in the Basque Country and Catalonia to form a minority left-wing coalition government.

However, while showing sympathy is good, how does Sanchez explain to his voters that he supports Palestinian independence, but not that of Catalunya and Basque country?
Another example is the former Spanish foreign minister Josep Borrell, who in his current position as charged of the EU foreign affairs has expressed his strong support for Palestinian self-determination:
January 3, 2024: EU's Borrell says world must impose solution to Gaza conflict
January 19, 2024: EU's foreign policy chief says: 'Impose' Palestinian state if need be
However, Borrell is known as a strong opponent of Catalan secession:

He also stood out as one of the most outspoken opponents of Catalan secessionism. Borrell co-authored Las cuentas y los cuentos de la independencia ("The calculations and tales behind independence"), a 2015 essay that vowed to dismantle the economic arguments laid out by the pro-independence movement.[74] He also took a leading role in a mass rally defending the unity of Spain held in Barcelona on 8 October 2017, in which Borrell gave an impassionated speech demanding "not to bring up more frontiers" while displaying a European Union flag that he called "our estelada" (starred flag),[75][76][77] bringing him back to the media first line.[78][79] He also took part on a second mass rally on 29 October 2017 under the slogan "We are all Catalonia".[80][81]

Background
Catalan and Basque struggle for independence date back as long as the Palestinian one, with both regions notably conflating their independence struggle with anti-fascist one during the Spanish civil war, the well-known notable episode being the bombing of the Basque city of Guernica/Gernika. More recently Basques separatists/freedom fighters engaged in a military struggle against Spanish government/occupation, whereas the organizers of the Catalan 2017 independence referendum were tried for sedition and rebellion.
I am interested in quotes from Sanchez, Borrell and others on why they support Palestinian state, but not ones for Catalans or Basques.
Remarks

The assertion about Spain recognizing Palestinian state is based on the Spanish government's declarations to this end, e.g.:
El País: Sánchez planea el reconocimiento del Estado de Palestina antes del verano (Sánchez plans the recognition of the State of Palestine before the summer)
The question is about the statehood, not about the rights of the Palestinian population (If Sanchez wanted the Palestinians to have the same rights as Israeli citizens, he should have advocated for a one-state solution, which would be more in line with his stance on Catalunya and Basques.)
The question is not about whether the Spanish policy constitutes "double standards" (which is a moral judgement), but how the government explains the difference in policy to its own population, as well as to Catalans and Basques.


@ccprog If Sanchez is doing what the source suspects - this is based on the Sanchez' own declarations. The question is not so much about double standards, but how this is explained to Basques and Catalans.

Apart from @Rekesoft's point that support for Palestinian independence is not an independentist only issue, but happens mostly following the left/right divide as in most Western countries.
Catalonian and Basques are full Spanish citizens, even if some of them would wish otherwise. They have full civil and political rights. They can vote for their local government and the national one, and in fact political parties from those regions have often had the opportunity to act as king makers, getting a very high influence.
It is hard to see similarities with the current situation in Palestine.
Now, if we were talking about an scenario in which the Israel government wants to make Palestinians full citizens of Israel and unite the region into a single country without second class citizens (if we can even consider Palestinians "citizens" at all), then maybe I could see some parallels between the situations. But I think that we agree that full Israeli citizenship for Palestinians is not a reasonable solution for the foreseeable future.

They don't
I don't know who this Cristina López is, or why she can't be just speaking out of her ass. Nobody compares the situation in Catalonia or the Basque Country with Palestine. Not the Spanish government, nor the opposition, nor the independentist parties. As such, there's no one pressing them to explain this incongruencies, which are mostly not perceived as incongruencies by nobody, even the independist parties.
Spain is, alongside Ireland, one of the most pro-palestinian countries in Europe, especially among left-wing voters. The current president, Pedro Sánchez, is from a center-left party governing (the same one of the UE High Representative, Josep Borrell, who also has expressed the harshest criticism from the EU to Israel) in coalition with a more leftist party, and the support of several left-wing nationalist and independentist parties from Catalonia and the Basque Country - and the way more unpredictable and half-hearted occasional support of a right-wing Catalan independist one. As such, his position in the Israel-Palestine conflict just aligns with that of his voters, not just with the independentist electorate.

This doesn't answer the question, which is about the contradiction between the declared policy on Palestinian, Catalan, and Basque statehoods.

This is a frame challenge. It states that nobody's asking to reconcile the government's views on Palestine to those of Catalonia and the Basque Country. Not even the independentists - among which there are lots of pro-Israel sympathizers, especially among right-wing nationalists. You could ask as well how does Sánchez reconcile his views on the recognition of the State of Palestine with his views on whether the Spanish omelette should contains onions or not. Now, if you were speaking about Western Sahara... but they have ditched that one too.
